# How to test if Spring Security is actually enabled?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having trouble getting Spring Security to work in my Spring MVC app. It is configured correctly (I think) and I am fully expecting it to use the configured security filter on all requests. It isn't. My question isn't to make sure I'm configured correctly so I'm not going to post any code, I am only asking if there is a method or something I can call in one of my controllers that will return `true` or `false` signifying if Spring Security is actually enabled or not so I can know how to proceed debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use **spring actuator**.

This is module used for application monitoring. You can read more about it, in this blog post: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

Comment: I'm not using Spring Boot, and I'd really prefer not to add a dependency for something like this. I appreciate your answer though thank you.